# Draw curved path inside circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

How to draw the curved line inside the red circle in this picture :
[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center] {Client};
      \draw[color=red] (0,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, text width=1.5cm, color=black, align=center] {Homme du milieu};
      \draw (2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center, text width=1cm] {Serveur web};
      \draw[color=blue] (-2, 0) -- (-.4,0);
      \draw[color=blue] (.4, 0) -- (2,0);

      \draw[-, color=red] (-.4,0) to[out=-30,in=100,looseness=2] (.4,0) ;
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How does function the `to[out=-30,in=100,looseness=2]` work?. I read an answer that suggested using it for making curved paths but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest to use named circle nodes. If the red one is called `hdm` you can use something like

```
\draw[red,looseness=1.5] (hdm.west) to[out=70,in =110] (hdm.center) to [out=-70,in=-110](hdm.east);
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=.8cm}]
      \node[mycircle,label=below:Client](client)at (-2,0){};
      \node[mycircle,red,label={[text width=1.5cm,align=center]below:Homme du milieu}](hdm){};
     \node[mycircle,label=below:Server web](sweb)at (2,0){};
      \draw[color=blue] (client.center) -- (hdm) -- (sweb.center);
      \draw[red,looseness=1.5] (hdm.west) to[out=70,in =110] (hdm.center) to [out=-70,in=-110](hdm.east);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a picture to explain how

```
\draw[looseness=1.5] (hdm.west) to[out=70,in =110] (hdm.center) to [out=-70,in=-110](hdm.east);
```

works (`looseness=0.5` is green, `looseness=1.5` is orange and `loosness=2` is blue):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      [myangle/.style={draw=red,thick,angle radius=1cm,fill=blue!10,fill opacity=0.5,}]
      \node[draw,circle,minimum size=8cm](hdm){};
      \foreach \l/\c in {0.5/green,1.5/orange,2/blue}
        \draw[thick,dashed,\c,looseness=\l] 
          (hdm.west) to[out=70,in =110] node[below]{\l}(hdm.center) to [out=-70,in=-110](hdm.east);
      \draw[help lines,thick]([xshift=-1cm]hdm.west)--([xshift=1cm]hdm.east)coordinate(H);
      \draw(hdm.west)coordinate[label=below left:hdm.west](A)--+(70:2)coordinate(B)
           (hdm.center)coordinate[label=below left:hdm.center](C)--+(110:2)coordinate(D)--+(-70:2)coordinate(E)
           (hdm.east)coordinate[label=above right:hdm.east](F)--+(-110:2)coordinate(G);
      \pic[myangle,->,"70\textdegree"]{angle=C--A--B};
      \pic[myangle,->,"110\textdegree"]{angle=F--C--D};
      \pic[myangle,<-|,"-70\textdegree"]{angle=E--C--F};
      \pic[myangle,<-,"-110\textdegree"]{angle=G--F--H};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer. As your angles are oriented, they should be +70 and +110 instead of -70 and -110.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have changed the orientation of the two angles.

Answer (score 8):

For completness, another answer which uses `pic` to store the "ying-yang" shape. This feature requires PGF 3.0.0

### Styles and pic definitions

```
\tikzset{
    entity/.style = {
        draw, circle, minimum size=0.8cm
    },
    mylabel/.style = {
        below=.5cm, text centered,
        text width=2cm
    },
    ying yang/.pic = {
     \node[entity, pic actions] (-edge) at (0,0) {};
     \draw let \p1=($(-edge.west)-(-edge.center)$),
               \n1={veclen(\p1)-0.5\pgflinewidth}
           in (-\n1,0) .. controls +(90:0.8*\n1) and +(90:0.8*\n1)
              .. (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.8*\n1) and +(-90:0.8*\n1)
              .. (\n1,0);
    },
}
```

With above settings, it is possible to `\draw pic {ying yang}` anywhere, and also some additional styles can be "passed" to the pic (line color, fill color, line width). In addition, we can also give a name to the shape when it is drawn, for example: `\draw pic (A) {ying-yang}`. Sice the code of the `pic` (above) defines a node name `(-edge)`, both names are combined, and the name `(A-edge)` can be used later in the tikzpicture to refer to the circular shape of the ying-yang.

Now, some examples of use of this `pic`.

### As requested by the OP

This is the code of the figure requested by the OP, using this new `pic`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[entity] (client) at (-2,0) {};
    \draw (0,0) pic (middleman) [fill=red!20, draw=red] {ying yang};
    \node[entity] (server) at (2,0) {};
    % Label the nodes
    \path (client)         node[mylabel] {Client}
          (server)         node[mylabel] {Serveur\\web}
          (middleman-edge) node[mylabel] {Home du millieu};
    % Connect with lines
    \draw (client.center) -- (middleman-edge) -- (server.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

## Sloped

One advantage of this `pic` is that it can be placed anywhere in a curve, and even sloped:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) .. controls +(2,0) and +(-2,0).. (3,3)
       foreach \t in {0,0.2,...,1.0} {
          pic[pos=\t, fill=yellow!20, sloped] {ying yang}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Sloped]

## Automatic intersections

Lines drawn to the `(name-edge)` refer to the inner circle node, so the intersections with its shape are automatically computed. In the following example, the `pic` is drawn without inner fill, but the lines drawn from outside stop at the edge, not at the center:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {A};           % Simply a char
    \draw    (0,0) pic (A) {ying yang};  % Not filled, the A can be seen below

    % Draw lines to A-edge. Intersections automatically computed
    \foreach \a in {0,10,...,350}
       \draw (\a:2) -- (A-edge);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Edges]

### Anchor names

Not only we have acces to `(name-edge)`, but also to its anchors (eg: `(name-edge.north)`, `(name-edge.center)` and eve `(name-edge.30)` etc.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw    (0,0) pic (A) [fill=blue!20] {ying yang};
    \draw    (2,0) pic (B) [fill=green!20, thick] {ying yang};
    \draw[->] (A-edge.north) to[out=90, in=30] (B-edge.45);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

This is a possible solution where `arc` is used to draw half cycle of a circle

```
  \draw[-, color=red] (-0.4,0) arc (180:0:0.2cm)  (0,0) arc (-180:0:0.2cm);
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center] {Client};
      \draw[color=red] (0,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, text width=1.5cm, color=black, align=center] {Homme du milieu};
      \draw (2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center, text width=1cm] {Serveur web};
      \draw[color=blue] (-2, 0) -- (-.4,0);
      \draw[color=blue] (.4, 0) -- (2,0);
      \draw[-, color=red] (-0.4,0) arc (180:0:0.2cm)  (0,0) arc (-180:0:0.2cm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution with the use of `controls`:

```
\draw[-, color=red] (-0.4,0) to[controls=+(80:0.2) and +(100:0.2)]  (0,0) to[controls=+(-80:0.2) and +(-100:0.2)] (.4, 0);
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center] {Client};
      \draw[color=red] (0,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, text width=1.5cm, color=black, align=center] {Homme du milieu};
      \draw (2,0) circle (.4cm) node[below=.5cm, align=center, text width=1cm] {Serveur web};
      \draw[color=blue] (-2, 0) -- (-.4,0);
      \draw[color=blue] (.4, 0) -- (2,0);
      \draw[-, color=red] (-0.4,0) to[controls=+(80:0.2) and +(100:0.2)]  (0,0) to[controls=+(-80:0.2) and +(-100:0.2)] (.4, 0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will appreciate if you give explanation of how it work.

Comment: @user230137 It just draws bezier curves with control points at 0.2cm away at 80 degrees for example.  For more, section 70.3 of pgfmanual, pages 753--756.